# Request to web services failed using php, succeeded from windows client

Tags: soap, web, service, iis-7.5

I have written a web service using asp.net 2.0 and a simple method "HelloWorld" to test it. Here is the soap envelope which the server receives:

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>      <soap:Header>
>        <SoapAuthHeader xmlns="http://myservice.anywhere.net/">
>          <UserName>MyUser</UserName>
>          <Password>MyPassword</Password>
>        </SoapAuthHeader>
>      </soap:Header>
>      <soap:Body>
>        <HelloWorld xmlns="http://myservice.anywhere.net/">
>          <request>
>            &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
>            &lt;HelloWorld /&gt;
>          </request>
>        </HelloWorld>
>      </soap:Body>
>    </soap:Envelope>
> ```

My Problem is: If I send the request from a Windows Client with embedded wsdl it succeeds. If I send the request from php (or SoapUI) the request fails - the server gets no "request" string, means no content for the body.
The server receives in both cases the same soap envelope above (logged it with a trace extension).

Thanks for any help.

Harald

P.S. No matter if I use embedded XML or embedded string for the request.

Answer (score 0):

Using the asmx trace I have found the problem at least with SoapUI. The requested requirement category was "text/xml" and it got "application/soap+xml". I have disabled "Soap action" and the call succeeds.